# MySql InnoDb auto-increment pre-fetching values

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, auto-increment

How do I get future keys from a Mysql InnoDb?

Oracle and Postgres both have the concept of sequences and a nextval-function. Mysql seems to be a bit different.

Is there some easy sql statement to pull maybe 1000 future keys for a certain auto-increment field, and be sure no other transaction can pull these values at the same time or any time in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For InnoDb table you can do this:

- Start a transaction.
- Insert 1000 records.
- Commit the transaction.

> *Oracle and Postgres both have the concept of sequences and a nextval-function. Mysql seems to be a bit different.*

In MySQL you could do this to find next value -

```
SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM table_name;
```

But there is no guarantee that AUTO_INCREMENT works in the same way.

Comment: So you're saying there is no safe way for InnoDb to produce some unique sequence? There must be some way to get keys beforehand?

Comment: You can insert NULL into AUTO_INCREMENT field. It will force engine to generate new `id` itself.

Comment: Yeah but I want to resuse the keys for a other foreign key without having to do some akward fetching after inserting. I am using a batched insert, therefore I need the keys before inserting.

Comment: You can get MAX(id) + 1, and insert new records into with new id(+1).